# My Softwares can't record my voice

Tags: sound

My system's "Settings" tool can detect noise from my microphone but Discord and games can't. I changed a few settings in the system's builtin tool and in the pavucontrol, to no avail. It works fine on Windows so I know microphone is working. This was happening in 16.04 and now in 18.04. I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using a USB sound card from a chinese brand called U Green. Any ideas?

edit:

Settings can hear my mic:
[image]

Discord can't:
[image]

Comment: To be clear, the mic _does_ show up in pavucontrol?

Comment: @Amolith Yes it does. The sound bar (it's labeled `Input level`) for it in system "Settings - Sound" does go up and down when I select it and speak.

Comment: Make sure you've got the input device selected in Discord and the other games

Comment: I've tried that but doesn't work. For an unknown reason, mic works but no software can't detect noise from it.

Comment: @pomsky That's solved my problem, thanks. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @GuiImamura I won't recommend it. Duplicates have a role in the Stack Exchange network, they work as signposts. No harm in keeping this question :)